# php code to convert javascript object to string

Tags: php, javascript, yslow

I have php file from which i am trying to run firefox and getting yslow results. But yslow results are sent in object form some thing like [object Object]
results are sent using post method.
how can convert it into string in php code and display to web page???

Comment: Please add some more context. What are you sending from where to where using what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your object gets passed to `JSON.stringify` then is should be returned as string.

```
var a = { "ynumreq": { "score":85} }; // currently an [object Object]
var b = JSON.stringify(a, null); // now "b" is a string representation of "a", "{ "ynumreq": { "score":85} }"
```

If **b** is essentially what you're sending to the server like you mentioned where it is being POSTed, if you use json_decode to your PHP (as suggested), it should work.

```
print_r(json_decode($_POST['string_object'])); // in this case it's '{"ynumreq":{"score":85}}'
```

You should get

```
{"ynumreq":{"score":85}}stdClass Object
(
    [ynumreq] => stdClass Object
    (
        [score] => 85
    )
)
```

From there you can start getting values. This is from what I tested based on how you described your data.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit ambigues. it sounds like you are trying to post a javascript object which is getting converted to a string.

```
{foo:'bar'}.toString(); // return "[object Object]"
```

You need to serialize the object if you want to include it in POST data.

Comment: Its the result what i am getting from yslow. while computing the result the values are stored some thing like this: { "ynumreq": { "score":85} }, and while posting to php file they do JSON.stringify(params,null) where param contains the result. how can i fetch the result in my php file and display

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's sent as JSON which you can use the json_decode function -
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score -1):

The difference between JavaScript object string and JSON is that with JSON the variable name foo is enclosed in double quotes. json_decode doesn't work with JavaScript object strings.